# PHP include file from other folder

Tags: php

Hey I am trying to include a file inside another file in PHP
If i write the entire path it does it with out problem.

```
$route = "/var/www/vhosts/aldroenergia.com/testmovil.aldroenergia.com/src/recursos/php/fEmail.php";
include($route);
```

but i would like to include with out writing the whole path.
Im including the `fEmail.php` inside

```
/var/www/vhosts/aldroenergia.com/testmovil.aldroenergia.com/src/ajax/correos/file.php
```

I've tried `include("../../recursos/php/fEmail.php")` but didnt work.
I've tried `include(dirname(__FILE__."../../recursos/php/fEmail.php"));` but failed too.

this is the folder structure.

```
--src
    --recursos
       --php
         -fEmail.php
    --ajax
       --correos
          -file.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include(dirname(__FILE__."../../recursos/php/fEmail.php"));
```

when you are passing the result of `__FILE__` concatenate to the `../../recursos/php/fEmail.php` within the `dirname` function it will not work because It's a wrong path. 
you must instead past just `__FILE__` as parameter to `dirname` which will return the absolute path of the directory in which the `file.php` file is. after getting the contening directory path you can past the relative path to the `fEmail.php` file from `file.php` directory.

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../recursos/php/fEmail.php");
```

Answer (score 4):

Constants paths and `require` statements are relative to the current file youre in.
To keep track of your paths I would suggest to use a central config file and define your root path in it:

```
# ./src/config.php
define("ROOT", __DIR__);

# Later include config.php and use:
require_once(ROOT . "/src/recursos/php/fEmail.php");
```

Comment: Now I get error when trying to `include("../../config.php");`

Comment: From where do you include it? The path has to be relative to file. And I would recommend always use __DIR__ so you have absoulte paths. You can wrap it in `realpath` if you want to remove the `..` and `.`.
So for `file.php` it would be `require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../config.php");`